# What does a solution of a Diophantine equation in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ tell about general integer solution?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields

> Q: What does a solution of a Diophantine equation in $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and prime $p$ tell about general integer solution?

We know that if there are not any solutions of a Diophantine equation in $\mathbb{F}_p$ then there are not any solutions in integers. Is this the only reason to study solutions in $\mathbb{F}_p$ or there are other reasons?

I read these two Wikipedia articles [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Applications) and [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_principle) but couldn't find answer to this question.

Comment: It is not effective. Depending on the equation it is possible to use easier methods. Besides all this, the theory ceases to work if suddenly there are not certain factors.  Besides, this all only applies to binary forms.  I prefer the purely algebraic approach - it is more effective.

Answer (score 2):

For example, if $E$ is an elliptic curve over $\Bbb Q$, the number
of points of $E$ over all finite fields defines the Hasse-Weil L-function of $E$. The conjectures of Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer indicate that this
L-function determines the rank of the group of rational points on $E$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it might be interesting for you.

If you have solutions for all $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, then sometimes under certain conditions we can lift these solutions for the higher modulo $p$ powers $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z}$ (check [Hensel's Lemma][1]).

There is a ring, called the ring of $p$-adic integers, and denoted by $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, which contains $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subring and is somehow "made up" by the finite quotients $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z}$.

So for certain polynomial equations, this ring allows us to say things like: this equation has solutions in all the $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z}$ if and only it has solutions in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, and so if this is the case, it is a matter of investigating whether or not this solution lands in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$.

I don't know if you can find such a thing for finite fields $\mathbb{F}_{p^{k}}$ (note that for $k>1$ these are not the quotient rings I was talking above).

I'm still a student far from expert; the main reasons I found in algebraic number theory so far for studying finite fields are:

1. When you study prime ideal decomposition in algebraic number fields (ramification, etc); for example, the decomposition $(p)=\mathfrak{P}_{1}\dots\mathfrak{P}_{k}$ of a rational prime $p$ in some $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ allows you to consider the finite field extensions $\mathcal{O}_{K}/\mathfrak{P}_{i}$ over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$; and this extension codifies some  information about how $p$ decomposes.
2. In the local field case (which by the way has to do with the above $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$), there is a notion of Galois unramified extension; for such an extension, the Galois group is isomorphic to the Galois group of associated residue fields extension, which is a finite field extension; so, understanding Galois theory of finite fields helps you to get a handle on this important class of local field extensions.

I'm sure there are plenty of others I'm not aware about;